# Why is the apparent size of my VM's file system so large? and other space-related questions

Tags: disk-usage

First of all, this doesn't seem to cause any issues, I am simply curious. I've recently had some issues with my Linux VM running out of storage and I ran `ncdu` as root to see what was using up all the space. I noticed that when I scan the entire file system, it says:

[image]

which seems rather insane to me. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how Linux works? Also, how can I know how much space is allotted to me? For context, I am supposed to be limited to 3 GiB (someone who is not me is hosting the VM), but running Docker on there means it's been dumping several GiB into the void (in the /var/lib directory). The 3 GiB limit only seems to apply to the /user directory, which `ncdu` says takes up exactly 3 GiB. I have no idea where I'm going with this but I have many questions given I'm new to Linux.

Comment: You've provided few specifics; we don't know what Ubuntu product, what release of that product, nor what setup you've installed on it.  For my own system, I have a ~99GB partition allocated in my `/` folder and no separate home directory, yet if I look at disk usage it'll tell me ~24TB of space is being used... as much of my `mounts` are network storage located elsewhere.. but I access them via my local file-system (ie. where I mount them).  The setup configures all these specifics; and we've been given almost no detail (don't even know what Ubuntu product/release you started with).

Comment: here's a discussion [here](https://jensd.be/251/linux/expand-or-grow-a-file-system-on-linux-in-a-vmware-environment-without-downtime) about expanding/growing a file system on a Linux VM. There are plenty more references for you to explore with little effort.